# How to export oracle table into flat file?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am a novice Oracle user. I had a newbie question. How can I dump a table (in Oracle) to a flat file ? I need to export spefically two datatables. So far I have this but kind of confused.

```
exp userName/Password @DBName file=filename.dmp tables=tablename rows=y indexes=n triggers=n grants=n
```

what goes under file = filename.dmp? whats filename ? is that part of the syntax ?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `exp` doesn't generate "flat files", it generates dump files that you might use to `imp` into another instance.

Answer (score 0):

The path that you specify is the path on the *database server*, not on your local hard drive. You will have to connect to the server's machine and get the file.

Comment: That's not correct. Plain old *exp* works with local files, whereas *expdp* doesn't.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I assumed that the author runs the EXP command on database server.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm) and [there](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ) also [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump)

You have the details on how to do it through PL SQL.

*Answer reproduced from WIKI - ORAFAQ*

Execute the following commands to create a database directory. This directory must point to a valid directory on the same server as the database:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY DMPDIR AS '/opt/oracle';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DMPDIR TO SCOTT;
```

**PS: Oracle introduced a default directory from 10g R2, called DATA_PUMP_DIR, that can be used:**

```
SELECT
      DIRECTORY_PATH
FROM
      DBA_DIRECTORIES
WHERE
      DIRECTORY_NAME = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';

DIRECTORY_PATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/rdbms/log/
```

Now try the expdp

```
expdp scott/tiger DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=scott.dmp
```

Comment: thanks @realspirituals. That last link in your post really helped. I am reading through it. I actually needed Network import . If I come through any more question I will make another comment on  your post. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that with exp. try using spool in sqlplus

```
Spool c:\output.txt

select * from tablename;

Spool off
```